# Creating XML Docmument childnode avoid inside previous childnode

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to create a XML document from PHP code to get this:

```
<xml version="1.0">
<parada nombre="Test Name" total="Test TOTAL">
       <linea numero="TestN" destino="TestD" minutos="TestM"/>
       <linea2 numero="TestN" destino="TestD" minutos="TestM"/>
</parada>
```

I have this code on my PHP:

```
<?php


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$parada = $xml->addChild('parada');
$parada->addAttribute('nombre', 'Test Name');
$parada->addAttribute('total', 'Test TOTAL');

$linea = $parada->addChild('linea');

$linea->addAttribute('numero', 'TestN');
$linea->addAttribute('destino', 'TestD');
$linea->addAttribute('minutos', 'TestM');


$linea2 = $parada->addChild('linea2');

$linea2->addAttribute('numero', 'TestN');
$linea2->addAttribute('destino', 'TestD');
$linea2->addAttribute('minutos', 'TestM');


echo $xml;          

echo $xml->asXML();
```

?>

But my result is this:

```
    <xml>
         <parada nombre="Test Name" total="Test TOTAL">
             <linea numero="TestN" destino="TestD" minutos="TestM">
                 <linea2 numero="TestN" destino="TestD" minutos="TestM"/>
             </linea>
        </parada>
    </xml>
```

I don't know  why the second childnode "linea2" is inside the first childnode "linea".

Thanks.

Comment: It's working correctly [in my test](http://viper-7.com/QN4CXz).

Comment: I *highly* recommend using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for constructing XML instead of SimpleXML - SimpleXML is great for reading, not so great for writing. Although the above code does produce your desired result for me.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you just forgot that the `<?xml` tag is not `<xml>` tag. If you want to put `<prada>` as root you just have to put it as the first argument of the SimpleXMLElement constructor

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement("<prada></prada>");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but my problem is not put <parada> as root is that <linea2> node appear inside <linea> node instead of <parada> as <linea>

Comment: Yes... The child linea2 still appear with parent linea instead of parada.

Comment: This is a screencapture of the result of execution code
http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6410/screenshot20130121at152.png